# New Family Membership Not Creating Memberships for Related Members for Existing Household

Tags: civimember, households

CiviCRM has inconsistent behavior when creating Family memberships for a household. If a brand new family joins, I enter the household and the family members, setting the members' addresses with the "use another contact's address" option and checking the "create a household member relationship with this contact" box. Then when I create the family membership, it creates the related memberships. This is all good, working fine.

But when I have an existing family with no membership or an expired membership, the related memberships are not created, as evidenced by "0 created" in the Related column of the Active Memberships table. The family members appear as relationships in the Household record, so they are related. Yet every time when I create a new Family membership for an existing household, the related memberships aren't created. I can confirm this by going to the contact record for a family member, which shows that they aren't a member.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

I am entering all this manually in the backend, so it's not a forms thing.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: What happens if you edit/save the relationship for the h/hold where the h/hold members are not showing a Membership?

Comment: That creates the related membership for the family members. But surely that's not what I have to do every time? Although it's good to know that's a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: i thought this issue had been fixed. i checked Scheduled Jobs and don't see it there. What version of civi are you on

Comment: Version 5.50.4. This is on WordPress.